# Rename [iproute] to [iproute2]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

`iproute2` is the package name for the utility `/sbin/ip` and its peripherals. `iproute` OTOH leans strongly towards the `ip route` subcommand. While I admit that `ip route` is probably the most used subcommand of `/sbin/ip`, I would still like to see `iproute2` as the canonical name being used for the tag, rather than `iproute`. Shall we rename [iproute](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iproute) to [iproute2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iproute2)? (Probably retaining [iproute](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iproute) as a synonym)

Comment: Some distributions still package this in the `iproute` package, but the upstream project name is [iproute2](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2).

Comment: Related, on the main site: [What is the relation between iproute and iproute2?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/363618/315749)